# How to delete multiple dynamic textbox

Tags: javascript

I have here my JS code that dynamically add textboxes.. I want to add another button that removes these textbox in case add button is accidentally clicked. Thanks!

```
<script language="javascript">
  row_no=0;
  function addRow(tbl,row){
    row_no++;
    if (row_no<=20){
      if (row_no<=20){
        if (row_no>=10){
           var textbox  = row_no+'.)&nbsp;<input type="text" size = "50"  maxlength= "50" name= "desk_user[]">';
        }
        if (row_no<10){
           var textbox  = row_no+'.  )&nbsp;<input type="text" size = "20"  maxlength= "50" name= "desk_user[]">';
        }
        var textbox2 = '<input type="text" size = "60" maxlength= "250" name= "desk_report[]">';
        var textbox3 = '<input type="text" size = "60" maxlength= "250" name= "desk_action[]">';

        var tbl = document.getElementById(tbl);
        var rowIndex = document.getElementById(row).value;
        var newRow = tbl.insertRow(row_no);
        var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
        newCell.innerHTML = textbox;
        var newCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
        newCell.innerHTML = textbox2;
        var newCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
        newCell.innerHTML = textbox3;
      }
      if (row_no>20){
        alert ("Too Many Items. Limit of 20."); 
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove all the input elements which you have add dynamically??
Is there any other contents available in the element in which you add those input elements?
If not and if you want to remove all the elements then try the following code..

```
for(i=0; i < row_no; i++){
   newRow.insertCell(i).innerHTML = '';
}
```

If this is not what you want then just modify your question to get proper answer. Because not specially said whether you need to remove all elements or particular elements and whether do you have any other contents in the element in which you add those input elements.